# How can I align my form to the center of the background? CSS

Tags: css

I have the following form: http://imgur.com/8uV4729

with this CSS:

```
#myForm {
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
}
#myForm form {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
#myForm table {
    text-align: left;
}
```

here is a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/3d44j5to/4/

How could I align the form table so that it is in the middle of the screen and the grey background? How would I also go about putting 1 line of space between the form and the submit/reset button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]The table will take up the specified width, and the remaining space will be split equally between the two margins

```
table{
    margin: auto;
    width: 53%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

I'm also remove the size attrbut from th adress input

```
<input type="text" id="homeaddress" name="homeaddress"  />
```

I update your jsfiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/s3mcrk39/8/